# What can i do to make my code look good on 2 different screens

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {    
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 15%;   
}    
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;    
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.floated {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}      
hr {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #333; /* old IE */
  background-color: #333; /* Modern Browsers */
}     
</style>
```

This is the css code for columns, inside these columns i have some icons and text displayed, it may look perfect on my screen, but look ruined on a laptop screen, what can i do to make it look good on every screen? I'm using % instead of px so it should set the height depending on the size of the screen?

HTML code for a column below;

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#edeeef;">
<body>
<p style="float:left; margin: 0 auto; cursor:pointer; border-radius: 50%;" onclick="location='http://localhost/badges.php?wear=<?php echo $b_id; ?>'"><?php echo $userbadge; ?></p>
<p style="float:left; margin: 15px 20px; font-size:19px; cursor:pointer; color:black" align="center"><?php echo $badgedesc; ?></p><p></p>
</body>
      </div>
```

Comment: have you HTML? so please set HTML for more understanding

Comment: share you HTML code here

Comment: You should use media queries for laptop screen with different css.

Comment: and how's that done?

Comment: You can use media queries to adjust your css for different viewport size

Comment: You've got errors in your HTML, in this case the `<body>` and `</body>` tags in random places. Fix that first. Also, there's only one `.column` in your code, is that right?

Comment: This is not about errors, it's about making it look good on 2 screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use @media screen and (min-width:1000px){} with whatever dimensions suits you best, put alternate css inside the brackets of this query to set the styling for screen sizes that comply with the declaration.

e.g. any style put in this query will only apply to screen wider that 1000px
use developer tools to see at what widths you want to adjust the styling.

edit: You can also change the rule to 'max-width' if that helps, try researching css3 media queries to develop your own understanding fully

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

> Media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style
>   sheet to different devices.

```
    // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

---

or you can use [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) and add pre defined classes to your elements

> Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns
>   to layout and align content. It’s built with flexbox and is fully
>   responsive.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```